# How do I force HTTP on my feed in Wordpress while keeping everything else SSL enabled?

Tags: wordpress, apache, ssl, rss, feedburner

I need to disable SSL only on the feed url so I can use Feedburner.  In my settings I entered a url of https://site.com and as expected all pages are displayed using SSL.  But of course that also means that the feed is forced to https, which Feedburner does not like.  I've tried various plugins with no success, and even if they did work, I would prefer to have the entire site secured via SSL anyway given the nature of the non-public facing data/information.

Wordpress does not appear to be using Apache rewrite rules to force SSL, so editing .htaccess does not appear to be an option either, but I could be wrong.

Surely someone out there has site-wide SSL enabled with Wordpress and has figured out how to exclude certain pages or slugs, right? How can I do this? Thanks much!

Comment: I have a similar question open at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617597/htaccess-force-ssl-except-for-rss-feeds

Comment: Thanks - Can you explain why you elected to go with forcing SSL via the .htaccess change versus just plugging https: into your Wordpress settings?  Was it so you could exclude certain urls?  If so, how do you prevent Wordpress from redirecting back to http: (or perhaps it does, thus the looping you describe)?