# htaccess force ssl except for rss feeds

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, rss

My site currently forces SSL everywhere. This is the way that I want except that it is causing issues with my RSS driven newsletter and feedburner. Due to this I need to make exceptions for my feeds.

Can someone help with the proper htaccess rules to pull this off?

My feeds are

```
/feed
/shop/feed
/forum/discussions/feed.rss
```

Here is my condition for forcing SSL. This works except that all RSS feeds are forced to.

```
# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forum [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://photoboothowners.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L,NE]
```

I tried the following but it did not seem to work correctly.

```
# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forum [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/feed [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop/forum [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://photoboothowners.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L,NE]
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!

---

Update: This is my current .htaccess file in the root of my server. This is currently redirecting http://photoboothowners.com/feed to https://photoboothowners.com (notice it is dropping the feed directory).

```
RewriteEngine on


# Use PHP5CGI as default
AddHandler fcgid-script .php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^buyaphotobooth\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.buyaphotobooth\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/photoboothowners\.com\/starting\-a\-photo\-booth\-business\-build\-or\-buy" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^photoboothforums\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.photoboothforums\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/photoboothowners\.com\/forum" [R=301,L]

# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forum [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !feed   [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://photoboothowners.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L,NE]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^photoboothowners\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.photoboothowners\.com$
RewriteRule ^how\-to\-use\-our\-premium\-print\-designs\-in\-breeze\-dslr\-remote\-pro\/?(.*)$ "https\:\/\/photoboothowners\.com\/how\-to\-use\-our\-photo\-booth\-template\-designs\-in\-breeze\-dslr\-remote\-pro$1" [R=301,L]

RewriteOptions inherit

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^shop\/photo\-booth\-layouts\-and\-samples\.html$ "https\:\/\/photoboothowners\.com\/shop" [R=301,L]

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rules are using `OR` so they read as:

`if server port is 80 and the request is not forum OR it is not feed OR it is not shop/forum`

That's going to match everything. Get rid of both of the `[OR]` so that the match reads:

`if server port is 80 and the request is not forum AND it is not feed AND it is not shop/forum`

EDIT:

Per your updated question, the following line is missing a slash:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !feed   [NC]`

should be

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/feed   [NC]`

Comment: Thanks I had already done this. I appended the full .htaccess file to my original question.

Comment: Unfortunately no change. I did try adding the following. This caused an infinite loop telling me I am missing something that is forcing to SSL. I am now wondering if having my base WP URL set to https://mysite.com is causing this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /feed 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://photoboothowners.com/feed [L]`

Comment: I haven't used WordPress, but I know other CMS have their own https settings that may rewrite independently of Apache. One troubleshooting step you can take regarding the https redirect rule is to split `/feed` and `/forum` into separate rules ahead of the redirect rule. Ultimately they would be like `RewriteRule ^feed.* - [L]`, meaning "don't mess with anything starting with feed," but for troubleshooting you would redirect them somewhere obvious instead so you could ensure they were matching, (e.g. RewriteRule ^feed.* http://www.google.com/ [R=301, L]`).

Comment: I think you are right David as it is still redirecting to my home page using https when using your first suggestion. I receive a 500 error when using your second suggestion.

Comment: Oops ... if by second suggestion, you mean the google.com rewrite, I must have inadvertently abbreviated it, it needs the full URL like: `RewriteRule ^feed.* http://www.google.com [R=301, L]`

Comment: No it was the first suggestion that threw the 500